# How to change instance in Django with hyperlinks?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django. I want to change a specific field of a model with an hyperlink but I don't know how to do. I tried this but it makes nothing.

views.py:

```
def sGiocatore(request, giocatore_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Giocatore, pk=giocatore_id)
    item.fantasquadra=None #or something else
    return redirect('/sondaggio/fantasquadre')
```

urls.py:

```
path('svincola/<int:giocatore_id>/', views.sGiocatore, name='s_player'),
```

forms.py:

```
class EditGiocatoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Giocatore
    fields = ['fantasquadra']
```

lista.html:

```
{% for fantasquadra in elenco_fantasquadre %}
<p><b>{{ fantasquadra.nome_fantasquadra }}:</b></p>
<table id="customers">
{%for giocatore in elenco_giocatori%}
{% if giocatore.fantasquadra.nome_fantasquadra == 
fantasquadra.nome_fantasquadra %}
<tr><th>Nome</th><th>Cognome</th><th>N° Maglia</th><th>Squadra</th> 
<th>Ruolo</th><th>Svincola</th></tr>
<tr><td>{{ giocatore.nome_giocatore }}</td>
<td>{{ giocatore.cognome_giocatore }}</td>
<td>{{giocatore.numero_maglia}}</td>
<td>{{giocatore.squadra.nome_squadra}}</td>
<td>{{giocatore.ruolo.ruolo}}</td>
<td><a href="/sondaggio/svincola/{{giocatore.id}}">Svincola</a></td></tr> 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more. seems like you forget to call `item.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `item.save()` after making changes.